# Microsoft flow using IF with OR

Tags: workflow

I need to add an `if` statement to an email:

```
if(equals(body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'],'Badania lekarskie'),'Inne', body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'])
```

This `if` work correctly.

Now I need convert this `if` and add `OR`, so I added:

```
if((equals(body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'],'Badania lekarskie') or (equals(body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'],'Inna nieobecność (kod 350)')),'Inne', body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'])
```

But flow return me alert:

> the expression is incorrect

**How can I use `OR` in an `IF` statement?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found resolve, this is correctly used `or`:

```
if(or(equals(body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'],'Badania lekarskie'), equals(body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'],'Inna nieobecność (kod 350)')) ,'Inne', body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'])
```

Comment: Hmm...In my formula there is an extra bracket/paranthesis before first `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have missing paranthesis. try using this:

```
if(or((equals(body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'],'Badania lekarskie')),(equals(body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'],'Inna nieobecność (kod 350)'))),'Inne', body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'])
```

**References**:

1. [Use expressions in conditions to check multiple values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/use-expressions-in-conditions#use-the-or-expression).

Comment: No, still I have this same error: the expression is incorrect

Comment: Try using @or function. see updated formula in answer

Comment: Still this same error, I will try to use this answer [link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Using-AND-OR-in-same-condition/m-p/118443#M11466)

Comment: try removing `@` before `or`.

Comment: I removed, but still I have error

Comment: Please upvote if it helped you to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi IF Statement have (Condition,True,False), so you need to use it this way:

- `if(or(equals(items('Apply_to_each'),'TEXT1'),equals(items('Apply_to_each'),'TEXT2')),'TRUE','FALSE')`
- `if(or(equals(body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'],'Badania lekarskie'),equals(body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'],'TEXT2')),'Inne',body('Aktualizuj_element_2')?['Typ_x0020_urlopu']?['Value'])`

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: No, still I have this same error: the expression is incorrect

Comment: edited, the first working for me, the second is how it looks like for you